# Getting C2628 strange error from VSStudio with all semicolon there

Tags: c++, dll, exe

I'm using [embedFiglet](https://github.com/ebertolazzi/embedFiglet), an embeddable Figlet version. While I compile no problem on Os X, under Windows 10 with VS I receive a

```
..\dep\embedfiglet\src\Figlet.hh(341): error C2628: 'Figlet::Banner' followed by 'char' is illegal (did you forget a ';'?)
..\dep\embedfiglet\src\Figlet.hh(341): warning C4091: 'extern ': ignored on left of 'Figlet::Banner' when no variable is declared
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.16.27026.1

This is the code:

```
#ifndef FIGLET_HH
#define FIGLET_HH

#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>

/*! \brief
 * Collects structures and classes for banner generation
 */
namespace Figlet {

  using namespace std;

  typedef std::basic_ostream<char> ostream_type;

  static unsigned const maxHeight    = 10;  //!< maximum allowed (lines) height of the font 
  static unsigned const maxLenght    = 256; //!< maximum number of characters x line of the banner
  static unsigned const maxTableSize = 256; //!< maximum number of allowed character x font

  //! Structure used to store a charater of the font
  typedef struct {
    unsigned short nchar;              //!< character (ascii) number
    uint8_t        lspaces[maxHeight]; //!< number of spaces on the left side x line
    uint8_t        rspaces[maxHeight]; //!< number of spaces on the right side x line
    char const *   rows[maxHeight];    //!< charater definition
  } FontFiglet;

  //! Available way to print a string, see \ref printmode
  typedef enum {
    FIGLET_SMUSHED=0,
    FIGLET_PACKED,
    FIGLET_FULLWIDTH,
    FIGLET_MONOSPACED
  } PrintMode;

  //! Available way to print a frames string, see \ref framemode
  typedef enum { FIGLET_SINGLE=0, FIGLET_DOUBLE } FrameMode;

  //! Class implementing the "figlet" algorithm
  class Banner {

    FontFiglet const * characters; //!< pointer to the font structures
    char       const   Hardblank;  //!< character used for the "hardblank" in the font definition
    unsigned   const   Height;     //!< vertical dimension (lines) of the font
    unsigned           Width;      //!< width of the charater M used in Monospaced print
    unsigned   const   FontMaxLen; //!< maximum width of the letters of the font
    unsigned   const   FontSize;   //!< total number of characters in the font
    uint8_t            rspaces[maxHeight]; //!< extra right spaces availables after the last insertion
    char               lines[maxHeight][maxLenght]; //!< lines buffer 
    char               smush[maxHeight];            //!< charater used in the "smushing" algorithm
    unsigned short     charToTable[maxTableSize];   //!< map ascii character to font structure
    unsigned short     charWidth[maxTableSize];     //!< size width of each charater of the font
    unsigned           charPosition;                //!< position of last inserted character

    PrintMode          printMode; //!< the type of printing mode used

    Banner const & operator = ( Banner const & );
    Banner( Banner const & );

    //! evaluate smushing rules for 2 characters, return '\0' if no rules apply
    char smushingRules( char left, char right ) const;

    bool pushMonospaced( unsigned c );
    bool pushFullWidth( unsigned c );
    bool pushPacked( unsigned c );
    bool pushSmushed( unsigned c );
    void fillForPrint( char const message[] );

  public:

    //! Constructor of `Banner` class
    /*!
    :|: \param characters none
    :|: \param Hardblank  none
    :|: \param Height     none
    :|: \param FontMaxLen none
    :|: \param FontSize   none
    \*/
    explicit
    Banner( FontFiglet const * characters,
            char               Hardblank,
            unsigned           Height,
            unsigned           FontMaxLen,
            unsigned           FontSize );

    //! initialize Banner class
    void init();

    //! Set print mode to `monospaced`, see \ref printmode
    void setMonospaced() { printMode = FIGLET_MONOSPACED; }

    //! Set print mode to `full width`, see \ref printmode
    void setFullWidth() { printMode = FIGLET_FULLWIDTH; }

    //! Set print mode to `packed`, see \ref printmode
    void setPacked() { printMode = FIGLET_PACKED; }

    //! Set print mode to `smushed` (figlet default), see \ref printmode
    void setSmushed() { printMode = FIGLET_SMUSHED; }

    //! Print large letters of string `message` on stream `s`, see \ref printmode
    unsigned
    print(
      char const     message[],
      ostream_type & s        = cout,
      char const     top[]    = "",
      char const     bottom[] = ""
    );

    //! \ref framemode
    void
    printFramed(
      char const     message[],
      ostream_type & s  = cout,
      FrameMode      fm = FIGLET_SINGLE
    );
  };

  extern Banner big;      //!< instance `Banner` class using figlet font `big`
  extern Banner banner;   //!< instance `Banner` class using figlet font `banner`
  extern Banner doom;     //!< instance `Banner` class using figlet font `doom`
  extern Banner larry3d;  //!< instance `Banner` class using figlet font `larry3d`
  extern Banner mini;     //!< instance `Banner` class using figlet font `mini`
  extern Banner script;   //!< instance `Banner` class using figlet font `script`
  extern Banner small;    //!< instance `Banner` class using figlet font `small`
  extern Banner standard; //!< instance `Banner` class using figlet font `standard`
  extern Banner straight; //!< instance `Banner` class using figlet font `straight`
  extern Banner bulbhead; //!< instance `Banner` class using figlet font `bulbhead`

};

#endif

//
// eof: Figlet.hh
//
```

(Line 341 is the one with "extern Banner small;")

Now, unless my eyes are faltering me, I see all semicolons in place. I'm new to Windows environment, so I guess the problem must be something else. I've been able to compile correctly just a week ago. It worked. And now no more.

Can someone of you more expert guys shine a light, please?

Comment: `using namespace std;` is a header file. Very, very naughty. Do you really want to (potentially) break any code that includes this header?

Comment: Thx for underlining. I've missed that. This library is going to have another patch.

Answer (score 0):

Just testing compiling this code standalone using the [goldbolt](https://godbolt.org/) website works fine, with both Visual Studio (MSVC) and Clang.

I would guess that perhaps you have a define somewhere else in the file (or in an included header) that defines "small" to "char" (or something along those lines) but you are not showing that in the code section you pasted (did you test just this small section separately as well?).

Comment: A redefinition is possible. I'll hunt that. Thx.